# GDAL ogr2ogr Converting DateTime to String

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'll preface this by saying I'm brand new to using GDAL. I'm using it in the Linux (Ubuntu) terminal. The GDAL version is 3.0.4.

I'm using ogr2ogr to convert ESRI geodatabase feature classes to GeoJSON files and I've run into a curiosity. Here's the command I ran:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:3310 /mnt/Events/testout1.geojson /mnt/Events/20200910_Event_ArcPro_2_5.gdb.zip Event_Polygon
```

It gave me this warning: `Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support DateTime type for field CreateDate. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.` When I actually inspect the GeoJSON output everything seems fine. The field is of the DateTime type and has the correct values.

But since I'll be doing this iteratively for dozens of files, to be safe I decided to convert any DateTime fields to strings by using the `-fieldTypeToString` argument. Here's the command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:3310 -fieldTypeToString DateTime /mnt/Events/testout2.geojson /mnt/Events/20200910_Event_ArcPro_2_5.gdb.zip Event_Polygon
```

This worked without throwing any warning. But when I inspect the relevant fields in the new GeoJSON file, they're still of the DateTime type! At least that's what QGIS reads it as, and I used ogrinfo to confirm. Anyway, this doesn't actually seem to be a problem since the information is getting carried over properly, but I was curious if anyone had any insight into what's going on here. What if I truly wanted the field to be a string instead of DateTime? If GDAL is leaving the field as DateTime even when I tell it not to, why does it throw a warning about it? I should note that I also tried using -mapFieldType, as the warning suggests, with the same results.

Comment: GeoJSON / JSON doesn't have a dateTime type, so the warning would seem valid.  The GeoJSON driver (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#vector-geojson) wouldn't be give native support for a feature not natively supported.   It's a just a warning, it may not affect your situation.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense why the warning comes up. I'm still confused why the field gets identified as DateTime in the GeoJSON file if it (1) isn't a native field type, and (2) I've told it to convert it to a string. But you're right, it isn't affecting me now. I'm just curious.

Comment: It's the datetime in the input ESRI geodatabase that is identified as such, not the output GeoJSON.  I assume by using `fieldTypeToString` you are telling ogr2ogr you're addressing the issue, and the warning goes away.

Comment: I'm looking only at the output. It's identified as DateTime in the GeoJSON file.